# Apache Storm : maximum tuple size

Tags: limit, apache-storm

What is the maximum tuple size Apache Storm can handle (if any)?

I couldn't find any information about this in official Storm documentation, which leads me to think there is no limit (beside the heap size of course). On the storm-user mailing list, I found [a thread asking about this](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/storm-user/201505.mbox/%3cCALEEtgGabuXzJm6M=A2-b3G=Rs3GkoqMB184pjNc6ZD1cLj-rg@mail.gmail.com%3e), but it turned out the user's error was due to a serialization issue.

My topolgy needs to process tuples of a few megabytes and send them to Kafka. I'm currently hitting Kafka limit of 1MB, but before working on it, I want to know if there is any limit on Storm's side.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's a limit. Storm uses either Java serialization (not recommended for production workloads, but useful for prototyping) or [Kryo](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo) to send tuples between workers.